# Displaying Single Post from Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using the plugins and settings below. I am having some problems displaying my custom post types. I am concentrating on the printers custom post type. I have them displaying under the custom taxonomies section and have created 4 taxonomies (manufactures) so that bit is ok. (http://developmentscene.co/CKH/printers/)

**The Problem**
When I click on a post on the page above it displays all posts in that category. I just want it to display the post that the link you clicked on and only that post. I have tried to do this using ('posts_per_page' => 1,) But this bit of code just displays the same first post for each post I click on in the category page.

**My Ideal Solution**
So what I was thinking in my mind was to say only show one post with the ID of the link you clicked previously in the category. I dont know if this is the best way but I have put my code below.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="wrap" class="container">

    <section id="content" class="primary" role="main">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php $printers = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'printers',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
    )); ?>

    <?php while($printers->have_posts()) : $printers->the_post(the_ID()); ?>

    <h2 class="post-title" style="color:#333;" ><?php the_title(); ?> - <?php echo the_ID();?></h2>
    <hr >

    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <br />


    </section>

    <section id="sidebar" class="secondary clearfix" role="complementary">


    <h3 class="widgettitle" ><b>Features and Benefits</b></h3>


    <?php $benefits = get_field( "features-and-benefits" ); 
       if($benefits){
        echo '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody>' ;
            foreach($benefits as $benefits){
                echo '<tr><td><p>' . $benefits['features'] . '</p></td></tr>' ;
            }

        echo '</tbody></table>';
       }

    ?>
    <br />

    <h3 class="widgettitle" ><b>More Information</b></h3>

    <?php $specifications = get_field( "specifications" );; 
       if($specifications){
        echo '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody>' ;
            foreach($specifications as $specifications){
                echo '<tr><td><p>' . '<a target="_blank" href="http://' . $specifications['link'] . '/">' . $specifications['details'] . '</a></p></td></tr>' ;
            }

        echo '</tbody></table>';
       }

    ?>

    </section>

    <?php endwhile; ?>



</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Settings**

Plugins Used:
* Custom Fields
* Custom Post Type UI

I also have permalinks set to postname.

Comment: Why are you running two loops on the page

Comment: Hi Pieter, As I am new to Wordpress Development I was not aware I was doing this. I do apologize for my stupidity. Do you have any suggestions to improve my code?

Comment: No, your not stupid. You stay stupid by not asking questions :). I'll be home soon, will then have a proper look to improve your code

Answer (score 0):

You are running two loops here, and that is causing all the frustrations. I believe that you added the second loop for your specific needs, so can you can just simply delete the first loop, that is this section

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```